# .docker/config.json vs .dockercfg

Tags: docker, docker-machine

When I do a `docker login` to a private repository using docker 1.10.1, an entry is created in my `~/.docker/config.json` file.  Is this file in the same format as what I see being called a `.dockercfg` file?  Is the `config.json` file interchangeable with a `.dockercfg` file?

Answer (score 39):

I assume `config.json` is the new `.dockercfg` file.
See "[`docker/cliconfig/config.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/131e2bf12b2e1b3ee31b628a501f96bbb901f479/cliconfig/config.go)"

```
// ConfigFileName is the name of config file
ConfigFileName = "config.json"
oldConfigfile  = ".dockercfg"
```

The new config file is now documented under [`man/config-json.5.md`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/d13e8d84463025a82a59caaf8da1f25d2ab06bd6/man/config-json.5.md)

That was introduced in [commit 18c9b6c](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/18c9b6c6455f116ae59cde8544413b3d7d294a5e) in docker 1.7.0 (April 2015)

> ### Add `.docker/config.json` and support for HTTP Headers
>
> This PR does the following:
>
> - migrated `~/.dockerfg` to `~/.docker/config.json`.
>   The data is migrated but the old file remains in case its needed.

---

Note: since 2016:

- `config-json.5` to `docker-config-json.5`  ([commit a596d3d, docker docs-v1.12.0-2016-07-28](https://github.com/moby/moby/commit/a596d3d1cf0a40ce577b8d1ea5ceb807d93468f2) )
- the documentation was [moved to `docker/cli`](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/man/docker-config-json.5.md) ([commit b5579a4](https://github.com/moby/moby/commit/b5579a4ce33af4c1f67118e11b5a01008a36d26a), Docker v17.07.0-ce-rc1)

It differs from [`docker-daemon.8.md`](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/d13e8d84463025a82a59caaf8da1f25d2ab06bd6/man/docker-daemon.8.md) which uses by default `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, the **[daemon configuration file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file)** introduced with Docker v1.10.

So:

- `config.json` is for the [docker CLI](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#configuration-files)
- `daemon.json` is for the [dockerd (daemon) CLI](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/)

But the `config.json` (which applies to all containers) does not include [`docker run` network settings](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings): `--net=host` could not be specified in that config file.

---

Update 2021 (since 2017), as noted by [slm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33204/slm) in the comments:

> The credentials are now stored in whatever your OS makes use of for managing secrets.
> On MacOS they get stored under Keychain, you can find them by looking for "Docker Credentials" under All Items

You can see the project [**`docker/docker-credential-helpers`**](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers): a suite of programs to use native stores to keep Docker credentials safe.

See [docker login/Credentials Store](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store) for more.

Comment: What is the relationship between ./docker/config.json and /etc/docker/daemon.json? i know i can add proxy in config.json. But if i want to add "--net=host" to a config file, what should i do?

Comment: @Justalittlenoob I have edited the answer to address your comment/question.

Comment: Great, very detailed. Thanks:)

Comment: BTW, the credentials are now stored in whatever your OS makes use of for managing secrets. On MacOS they get stored under Keychain, you can find them by looking for "Docker Credentials" under All Items.

Comment: @slm Good point, thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility